# How to init git folder and fetch the old commit from github?

Tags: git

So I accidentally erased my .git folder from my project and after that made numerous changes to the files.
How do I go about adding the git repository now?

As it has uncommitted files, I tried git init, setting the remote to origin, and executing git fetch and pull, but it failed.

I tried stashing, but it says `You do not have the initial commit yet`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily salvage your repo by cloning to a different directory first, then copying over `.git` into your existing working tree. Now `git status` and `git diff` should show you your uncommitted changes again.